# Allow anonymous user to browse all the non-admin pages of the site anonymously

Tags: 7

I want to allow anonymous user to access all the pages depending on a particular session set. These pages can be:

1. Node - both published and unpublished
2. Views pages
3. Taxonomy terms
4. custom hook menu urls etc
   I am able to handle node pages using hook_node_access. But is there any common hook and any other approach that allows me to grant access for all the pages. 
   Also, for views if there is no permission for anonymous user, I should be able to grant permission depending on a session set.

Comment: No there’s no common hook for that, you’ll need to hook into each thing that you want to control access for separately. For entities you could override the `access callback` for every type, but views and custom pages aren’t entities.  Or relax permissions if it can be done in a way that makes sense for your requirements

Comment: @Clive Relax permissions? What do you suggest for views and custom pages?

Comment: Assign them a permission that anonymous users have. For example _Access Content_ is available to anon users in most sites. I don’t know what a “session set” is so I’m making assumptions about your requirements

Comment: Requirement is : Even if  view pages do not have permission for anonymous user, if there is a hash code/token in the url like ?hash=ABC then anonymous user should be able to browse the site anonymously and access all the pages (views pages, custom urls etc). If the user access the url with hash code I set a session like $_SESSION['xyz'] = 'token_value'. If this session is set i.e until user closes the browser user can access the pages.

Comment: Oh right, no there's no easy way to do that. Off the top of my head, patching `user_access` would be the simplest method. But it ill be bad for performance; you'll have to make sure pages aren't cached for anonymous users, which is obviously not a good thing

Comment: I am ready for all the complex solution, but I need to have performance effective solution. I thought of creating custom views_access plugin but this will need all the views to have this custom access plugin which also I do not want. Because I am handling this anonymous site browsing in a separate custom module, which may or may not be enabled and I do not want all the views to be dependent on my custom module.

Comment: It's not possible, think about it - on every single request for these pages, for every user, you need to either check the URL parameters to see if a hash is set, and/or the session for the same thing, and render something different. By definition that means you can't have full page caching. Personally I'd be re-thinking the whole solution, I don't see how what you're suggesting could work

Comment: Yes agree with you. Dropping the idea of custom views plugin. Also, I did not understand how I can use user_access and considering the cache issue as well. What do you suggest then as the solution for this - specially for the views pages?

Comment: @Clive What can be the solution for this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to spec something like that out